# Change eclipse formatting to indent only 4 spaces on newline after opening parenthesis

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to configure such a thing in eclipse java?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're looking for is Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style - Formatter - Edit... - Line Wrapping - Default indentation for wrapped lines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I've been looking for this for a while (but for C). I want the code to look like this for wrapped lines:

```
/*
 * Parameters
 */
class Example {
    void foo(int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3, int arg4,
        int arg5, int arg6) {
    }
};
```

However, Eclipse only allows you to specify the number of tabs to use, not whether to use tabs or spaces. The place I've been looking is in the Preferences under C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter > Edit Format button.

**Update:** This is doable, but the settings are a pain and it won't appear quite correctly on the screen. It **will** write the file properly however. Here we go:

- Click the "Edit" button in the preferences area mentioned above (replace "C/C++" with your language of choice)
- In the "Indentation" section,

  - Set "Tab Policy" to "Mixed"
  - Check the box for "Use tabs only for leading indentations"
  - Set "Indentation size" and "Tab size" both to 4
- In the "Line Wrapping" section:

  - Set "Default indentation for wrapped lines" to 1

**Word of warning: I have no idea how this might affect other indentation settings elsewhere in the Code Formatter preferences.**